# ImageView not changing image get from Gallery

Tags: android, android-studio, image-gallery

I am using this code for getting image from gallery or taking picture.
Taking picture works perfectly.
Picture taken from camera will show on imageview,
But unlike image taken from gallery, its always blank.

```
 public void fromCamera(int id) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(
            android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, IMAGE_CAPTURE);
}

public void fromGallery(int id) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Pick a Picture"),
            IMAGE_PICK);
}

public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
    try {
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return contentUri.getPath();
    }
}

private void imageFromCamera(int resultCode, Intent data) {
    this.mButtonCarPhoto.setImageBitmap((Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"));
    Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
    mSelectedImagePath = getRealPathFromURI(selectedImageUri);
    Log.e("Camera",mSelectedImagePath);
    // mBase64Image = CONVERT_IMG_BASE64(mSelectedImagePath);
}

private void imageFromGallery(int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
    String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
    assert cursor != null;
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
    mSelectedImagePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
    Log.e("Gallery",mSelectedImagePath);
    cursor.close();
    this.mButtonCarPhoto.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mSelectedImagePath));
    //mBase64Image = CONVERT_IMG_BASE64(mSelectedImagePath);*/
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case IMAGE_PICK:
                this.imageFromGallery(resultCode, data);
                break;
            case IMAGE_CAPTURE:
                this.imageFromCamera(resultCode, data);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

why this ?

```
intent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Pick a Picture"), IMAGE_PICK);
```

if you just wanna choose from gallery, remove theze lines from your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works perfectly for me:

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, 1);
```

and then override onActivityResult method:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode==1) {  // from gallery
        if (data != null) {
            Uri photoUri = data.getData();
            if (photoUri != null) {
                String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(photoUri, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                path = cursor.getString(columnIndex); // path is a static variable
                cursor.close();
                new GetImages().execute();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the inner class GetImages, that updates the image view in a Async Task:

```
 public class GetImages extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, JSONObject>
{
    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(Void... params)
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path.toString().trim());
        if (bitmap != null) {
            bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 500, 500, true);
            currentBitmap = bitmap; // current Bitmap is a static variable
            drawable = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap); // drawable is a static variable
            // salvataggio foto in locale
            db.open();
            String bitmapString = BitMapToString(bitmap);
            db.updateImage(bitmapString, userName);
            db.close();
            JSONObject json = savePhotoInRemote(bitmapString);
            return json;
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result)
    {
        imageview_photo.setBackground(drawable); // QUI AGGIORNI LA TUA IMAGE VIEW
    }
}
```